# is there any simple way to hashing strings / variables via javascript?

Tags: javascript, hash

how can hash a variable or strings by **javascript**???

i didnt find a way to **hashing** *strings or variables* by **js** .

i want to hash my variables to **`sha256`**.

with php codes we can hash the strings with `hash('sha256', $variables)` as well .

```
 <?php

     $variables =rand(602,2040);
     $var2= "my_String";
     $getHash = hash('sha256', $variables);
    //or//
     $getHash = hash('sha256', $var2);
```

but in js . how should it be done?

is there any **same method** or **function** to hash variables / strings with **javascript**?

Comment: this is too hard answer for me i think. im looking for better options like a functions. :)

Comment: Those libraries, discussed the linked question, provide “functions”. There are no similar functions defined in the core Web/HTML or JS API.

Comment: thx bro :)    ill try it